# How to access ethaddress.org funds if the private key is blurred out?

Tags: ether, private-key, paper-wallets, recovery

Tried out the [paperwallet](https://ryepdx.github.io/ethaddress.org/#/) and sent 1 ether to the address on the screen as a test.

After that I noticed the private key on it is blurred out. I generated another and found the same thing on the second. How to access my ether if the private key is blurred out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you mouseover the blurred private key code, the QR code sharpens (helps with security preventing shoulder-surfing, it seems). And if you print the page, the CSS of the page modifies itself to un-blur it when printed.

Same thing with the text representation of the private key; it's normally shown as a line of asterisks, but if you hover your mouse over it, it becomes the real hex key.